# NGINX Not showing directory contents

Tags: nginx, apache2, directory, files, http-status-code-403

I have some trouble with NGINX on my server. I previously used Apache.
When I try to request folder contents on my server (like, 192.168.0.128/files), I get a 403 Forbidden error. Anyone know how to solve this? I tried to give permissions blah blah blah, nothing worked.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You will want to confirm that [autoindex](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_autoindex_module.html) is on in for the location you've defined in nginx.conf. You don't give your config, but it seems like you'd want something like

```
location / {
    autoindex on;
    root </path/to/server/root>
    index index.html
}
```

Comment: (Also, if this answer helped you, consider selecting it as your preferred answer!)